# Setting CentOS 7 MTU in AWS

Tags: centos, amazon-web-services, linux-networking

Using the official CentOS 7 Marketplace AMI on an EC2 Instance, the network adapter appears to default to using Jumbo Frames:

```
ip link show

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: ens5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:09:37:73:0f:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

What is the best method for disabling this?
Why does it default to mtu 9001?

Editing **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens5** does not seem to be an option:

```
# Created by cloud-init on instance boot automatically, do not edit.
#
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEVICE=ens5
HWADDR=0a:09:37:73:0f:7a
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCTL=no
```

I would like the change to persist.

Comment: Is it causing a specific problem? Generally this is fine to have enabled.

Comment: AWS Redshift recommends not using Jumbo Frames on clients, and we are experiencing some kind of network issues.

Comment: You can fix that [easily enough](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-drop-issues.html) by a simple change in the security group for your Redshift cluster.

Comment: The page you linked is what led to asking the OP question. Really need to set the OS mtu setting. Thanks though

Comment: You really should change the security group if at all possible.

Comment: Yep we do, but it's not possible for some of the clusters that we don't control. Do you know if this Jumbo Frame is CentOS specific? AWS seems to think it's unusual to default to Jumbo Frames.

Comment: Jumbo frames are a feature of every operating system that can handle Ethernet, which today is every operating system. Using them gives you a boost in network throughput by reducing overhead, which means your app gets its data back faster, and can return its response to the user faster. Amazon gives [instructions for changing the MTU](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/network_mtu.html) for Amazon Linux 2 and Amazon Linux, but I don't see anything for CentOS. One of those two approaches that they give ought to work, though.